# Changing SQL user name to user name with period

Tags: sql, database

I have a couple of users that need to have a period in their db log in to match another system and I see it has been done to a couple users but not sure how it was done. I have a database called eiwdata. So the lets say the user was testtest. The user would exists in databases > eiwdata > security > users AS WELL as servername (in my case mfdata) > security > logins AS testtest. I need to be able to change testtest to test.test in both cases. I tried doing Alter user but keep getting errors bc of the period but i know it can be done as I see SQL users with the period in there. I then tried altering this table but it says Ad Hoc updates to system catalogs arent allowed. Any help appreciated. This is SQL 2005 mgmt studio

Answer (score 3):

Try to put brackets around the new username (the dotted one):

```
ALTER USER testtest WITH NAME = [test.test];
```

Otherwise the dot would be treated as separator between schema and username.